# Flutter: Fetch Geo-location in the background

Tags: dart, flutter, location, background-process

i need my app to send the current location over to an API in the background ,specifically when the app is closed. I found that there are restrictions as to how it can be implemented for IOS. Is there any solution in flutter to implement this for both platforms?

Comment: Upvote here https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator/issues/53

Comment: This might help you some way https://pub.dev/packages/background_location

Answer (score 1):

So far i have found a plugin that works in the background - except is it not free.

flutter_background_geolocation 1.7.3

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation

It does exactly what you would want - work in the background for both platforms, you can use it in development for free, but when you launch the app - you need to pay for it (Android platform).

Comment: is it free for ios? how do we find prices?